# Getting "retweet_count" from twitter Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter, tableview

I'm using [this tutorial](http://tutorials.veasoftware.com/2013/09/20/twitter-api-version-1-1-user-timeline-in-ios-7/) for twitter app. My array for feed:

```
     self.twitter_feed = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:response 
options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];
```

Now in cellForRowAtIndex method I'm loading information from each post:

```
NSDictionary *post = self.twitter_feed[indexPath.row];
textpost.text=post[@"text"];//textpost-UILabel
retweet_count.text=[post[@"retweet_count"] stringValue];//retweet_count-UILabel
```

Everything works fine except the retweet_count. When i'm using

```
retweet_count.text=post[@"retweet_count"];
```

I'm getting exception because `retweet_count` value is a integer so I'm using `stringValue` method. In running application all text was loading fine but my `retweet_count` label is still clear, but when I start scrolling the tableview retweet_count label starts getting the right retweets values for each post. What can i do to make this `retweet_count` values load in one-time with text?

Comment: I don't seem to understand your problem

Comment: retweet_count is not an integer. Integers can't be placed in NSDictionaries. What's the actual exception you're getting?

Comment: NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd24f460'
MCKapur, i loaded users feed from twitter to my tableview. All works fine (text,data,user.screen_name) except retweet_count (it starts loading only when start scrolling table).